# Links in bibliography displaying in different fonts

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am currently using the IEEE citation style to generate my bibliography. However, the links and DOIs are formatted differently than the body of the citation. How do I get them to conform to the same font and size?[image: What my problematic reference section currently looks like.]

A sample of code for generating this is as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{`my references`}
\printbibliography
```

The .bib code:

```
@article{Abkenari2015,
author = {Abkenari, Mehrdad and  Rezaei, Alireza and Pournayeb, Naghmeh},
doi = {10.5281/zenodo.1339604},
journal = {International Journal of Architectural, Civil and Construction Sciences},
pages = {1138--1142},
title = {{Recycling Construction Waste Materials to Reduce the Environmental Pollutants}},
year = {2015}
}
@misc{DenseNet,
    title={Densely Connected Convolutional Networks},
    author={Gao Huang and Zhuang Liu and Laurens van der Maaten and Kilian Q. Weinberger},
    year={2016},
    eprint={1608.06993},
    archivePrefix={arXiv},
    primaryClass={cs.CV}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please also tell us which document class you employ and whether you load (a) any font-related packages and (b) the `url` (or `xurl`) and/or `hyperref` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex` uses the facilities of the `url` package to typeset URLs and URL-like objects (DOIs, `eprint`s, ...).

By default `url` typesets URLs in `\ttfamily`, but you can request the normal document font with

```
\urlstyle{same}
```

Other possible calls for `\urlstyle` can be found in the [`url` package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\urlstyle{same}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,baez/online,ctan,markey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: URLs in same font as rest of the text.]

This also works if you load the `hyperref` or `xurl` package.